# Write to a CSV file from a hash perl

Tags: perl, csv, hash

I have a program that at the moment reads from **FILE 1** looking like the one below and matching certain characters. e.g

```
Type, Fruit, Description, quantity
tropical, banana, tasty and yummy, 5
tropical, grapefruit, bitter and not yummy, 2
... and so on
```

First of all I wanted to create hash of hashes for each 'Type', 'Fruit', 'Description', 'Quantity' and store the different values in the reference hashes. That works fine with the code below.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Text::CSV;

my %MacroA = ('Type' => {}, 'Fruit' => {}, 'Description' => {}, 'Quantity' =>  {});         

open (my $file, '<', 'FRUITIES.txt') or die $!;     

while (my $line = <$file>)                                                             {                                        

if ($line =~ /\b(tropical)\b,/) {                                   
$MacroA{Type}->{$1}++;
}

if ($line =~ /,\b(banana|grapefruit)\b,/) {                             
$MacroA{Fruit}->{$1}++;
}

if ($line =~ /,([\w\s]+?),/) {                                  
$MacroA{Description}->{$1}++;
}

if ($line =~ /,([\d]+?)/) {                             
$MacroA{Quantity}->{$1}++;
}
        }

close $file;
```

So my question is **How can I put this data(data is not fixed) into a csv file or anything related(maybe xls), that would be a table with columns for each hash of hashes ('Type', 'Fruit', 'Description', 'Quantity').**

Comment: Have you tried running your code? It has compilation errors. You should start by fixing them, then take a look at [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV) (which you seem to have already found yourself).

Comment: hi @simbabque yes this is not the original code, its just an example. I had a look at Text::CSV but im not sure how to use it.

Comment: @El_Commandantee if it only for your usage or you can write 'dirty' code, without modules and other things, you can write code with usage Perl core functions easy

Comment: Your orginal data is in pseudo-CSV form, but you process this data into a hash of counts of different words. Data like that isn't in tabular form and so can't really be expressed as CSV. Perhaps you should show the result you expect for the sample data you have shown. By the way what's wrong with grapefruit?!

Comment: @Borodin the result that i expect is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AgYHcnS4R6rhdElPNFlMdkZ4c0VIUXNmT01FVlVFN2c#gid=0                             (PS well grapefruits are bit bitter tahts why :))

Comment: @Borodin im doing the count just for reference, all i want is to store them in this hashes and then populate a .csv table

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the point of the hash. Your data is already in CSV format. If you import it into Google Docs just as it is it will appear in the format you asked for.

Comment: @Borodin The thing is that I will have a lot of this files, with the same structure but different length and I will want to merge them in a single csv file. Thats why I use the hashes

Comment: Then all you need to do is copy all the files into a single one, dropping the header line from all but the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that hashes of hashes is a good thing, but I think you're not storing it in a way you can retrieve it easily.

One way you could do it is like this.

```
{ id_1 => {
             data_1 => "blah",
             data_2 => "foo",
             ...
           },
  id_2 => {
             ...
           },
  ...
 }
```

First of all, you need to pick which column would be the "ID". This would determine the uniqueness of each ROW. Let's say for your example let's pick the fruit, since we're assuming there would be no two fruits that would appear in the same file. So we would have something like this:

```
{ banana => {
             type => "tropical",
             description => "tasty and yummy",
             ...
           },
  grapefruit => {
             ...
           },
  ...
 }
```

In order to change this back to CSV, we loop through the hashes.

```
my %fruit_data; #let's assume that this already has the data in it

foreach my $fruit ( keys %fruit_data ) { 

    #given the $fruit you can now access all the data you need
    my $type = %fruit_data{$fruit}{'type'};
    my $desc = %fruit_data{$fruit}{'description'};
    # etc...

    # then you may want to store them in a scalar in any order you want
    my $row = "$field,$type,$desc etc.\n";

    # then work your way from there

}
```

Answer (score 2):

For writing Excel files - you could use [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel).

About CSV files - originally you have the CSV-file with "," delimiter and "\n" string delimiters. If you want to write some array of hashrefs to CSV - better way to write down simple sub by yourself, smth like this one:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub write_csv {

  my ($array_ref, $fh) = @_;

  for my $row (@$array_ref) {
    print $fh join(',', map { $_, $row->{$_} } sort keys %$row), "\n";
  }
}

my $test = [
  {a => 1, ab => 2, type => '234k', count => '123'}, 
  {a => 3, ab => 2, type => 'some_type', count => 34},
];

open my $fh, '>', 'test.csv' or die $!;

write_csv($test, $fh);
```

Comment: Which, of coarse, fails on any cell that contains a delimiter.

Comment: I think the upvotes must be coming from people who are impressed by how obscure this code is. It certainly doesn't answer the question

Comment: Thanks for good PR, man. It answers at least the part of the question - howto write excel files with Perl, and how to write CSV files - so it gives general direction for right answer if you can tweak the code. Writing custom CSV-file according to requirements looks more like a freelance job, than just a question.